# N Tier Architecture for web application

Tags: rest, architecture

I am a little confused with the implementation of this with regards to my web application and was hoping to gain some clarification. I have read around and I understand the basic concepts of the N-tier architecture. However I have yet to come across one that mentions what part of the application goes where.

My application is structured like this.

Frontend <- Contains the View and Controller. This controller does minor functions such as processing forms and retrieving data from the Back End.

Backend <- Contains the Controller and Model. This Controller receives and sends data to and from the Frontend and Model. The Controller here does some data processing as well. The Model communicates with the database and receives the inputs from the Controller.

The Frontend communicates with my Back End via REST. Does this mean in a Web Server, Application Server, Database Server setup, my Frontend application would sit on the Web Server, my Backend would sit on the application server and my Database Server is connected to from my backend via an ip?

Is this correct? If so, how do applications that aren't split up like mine fit into this architecture?

Also, I have seen architectures where there is one Application Server serving up 2 Web Servers with the same front. Is that where the load balancer comes in?

Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking about 2 related, but independent things: N-tier architecture and horizontal scaling of each tier.

**N-tier architecture:** this basically splits your entire application into different layers and have each layer do a dedicated thing alone. These different layers will communicate amongst each other, either through network calls or RPCs. For example, a mobile app like Amazon might have the database tier, a caching tier, a backend tier (which communicates to both the database and caching tiers), a messaging tier (which can decouple the tiers), a front-end tier.

There can be different ways in which the tiers can communicate with each other. What you described is just one of the ways. Other way could be the front-end tier pushing messages to a message queue and the back-end tier working asynchronously by pulling messages from the queue and do the processing. It depends on the application and the end-end latency and real-time needs of the application.

**Scaling of the tiers:** each tier can be scaled by adding multiple machines and fronted by a load-balancer that splits the traffic to the machines in the tier. So now in your example, there will be a load-balancer on top of the front-end tier and all traffic from your client will go through the load balancer and end up in one of the 2 nodes.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering this. So does that mean I already am implementing this n tier architecture in my application design and that where I place these applications is what will facilitate scaling in the future?

Comment: Scaling will depend on which parts you need to scale. If you backend isn't scaling that well with your front-end, you will scale that independently (adding load balancer in the front)